# Explorer not loading files and previews

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, file-management

First of all, I hope not to post something it has been already asked because it's really hard to search for something like this. My problem has been going on since I installed Windows 10 for the first time (as soon as I saw the free update from 8.1) and I said to myself "Well, they will fix this in the future so let's wait". Years have passed but this problem is still here and it's becoming really annoying so I decided to ask for a solution. Many things happen and it is difficult to describe so, to simplify, I will make a list of the events that happen:

1) I'm surfing files with the explorer and, at some point (this is random, don't really know when it could happen) the explorer literally starts not showing previews of files (usually when I enter a folder full of images or movies) in every folder.

2) When this happens, if I close the explorer window and I open it again a can't see anything. No files, no settings, nothing. Just an infinite loading; here's a pic of what I mean:

[image: Explorer crashes]

3) To make it work again I have to open an explorer window, then open the task manager and reboot the explorer process. Doing this, I'm able to surf "simple" folders (like documents, or the root folder where I can see my HDDs) but If I come back on that directory full of files everything crash again.

4) If I reboot my computer, the explorer returns to work without problems and I also can enter that difficult folder. I don't know, maybe it's a continuous entering/exiting from certain folders that make it crash.

5) I already tried to clear the explorer chronology, I reinstalled Windows many times; no viruses, no strange problems solvable with an sfc scannow.

I would be really glad if you can help me with this, I'm at my wit's end. Thanks for now and sorry If I made mistakes with the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loading screen in the File explorer is usually the result of the a failure in creating thumbnails or similar errors.

Try the following solutions,

**Solution 1: Restarting Process**

1. Open the task manager.
2. You will find a background process named COM Surrogate.
   [image: COM Surrogate in Task Manager]
3. Right click on the process and click End Task.

This background process is responsible for creation of Thumbnails.

**Solution 2: Clearing Thumbnail Cache**

If the first solution did not work for you try this.

1. Open File Explorer.
2. Right-click the drive where Windows 10 is installed (usually C:), and select Properties.
   [image: c-disk-properties-dialog]
3. Click the Disk Cleanup button.
4. Check the Thumbnails option, and uncheck all the other options.
   [image: disk-cleanup-popup]
5. Click OK and then click Delete Files.

---

**Reference:**

1. [How to reset thumbnail cache](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10)

Comment: I always thought It was something related to thumbnails but I never knew how to solve it; I tried your solutions, so I found those processes and killed them and I also cleared the thumbnails cache; frankly I thought this would have worked but the problem is still here; at the moment rebooting the machine is the only solution but I cannot shut down Windows every time (or restart the explorer practically whenever I enter a folder).

Comment: Ok, I read the reference link of your post and I followed the cmd instructions and it worked! This is a partial solution I think but it's something anyway, so thanks a lot! I'm really curious about the problem, by the way, Windows 7 and 8.1 never showed problems like this.

Comment: @Fede Glad to know that it worked for you.